# Finding records that contains sets

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 sets - set of 'attribute_A' and set of 'attribute_B'.
I would only like to get these 'field', which have all of the entered attributes (attrubute_A, attribute_B).

Say we have:

```
TABLE 1 (tab1)
id   name
1    'clients'
2    'employees'
```

```
TABLE 2 (tab2)
user_id   tab1_id   shop
1         1         shop_A
2         2         shop_C
3         1         shop_B
3         2         shop_B
```

```
TABLE 3 (tab3)
table1_id   permissions
1           buying
2           buying
2           working
```

I wrote a query that works correctly for arguments in one set:

```
SELECT tab2.user_id FROM tab2
(... JOINS ...)
WHERE tab3.permissions IN ('working', 'buying')
GROUP BY tab2.user_id
HAVING count(DISTINCT tab3.permissions) = 2
```

Edit:
Lets say we have shops, group of users(clients, employees), every of that group has certain permissions.

Now i wanna to select only these members (user_ids) which got permissions to buying and working on shop_A and shop_C.

Comment: Currently, I filter only on the values ​​from set of attribute1. I would like to achieve something that only these 'field' will be displayed which have all attributes froms set1 and set2. Maybe intersect?

Comment: Tables have columns not fields. Besides that point I am finding it hard to understand your scenario. The use of `attribute1` and `attribute2` seemingly as column names and searched values doesn't help. I suggest you edit your question to include sample data for all the tables you want to search and your required output derived from that sample.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you an use `intersect`:

```
SELECT t2.user_id
FROM tab2 t2 JOIN
     tab3 t3
     ON t2.tab1_id = t3.tab1_id
WHERE tab3.permissions IN ('working', 'buying')
GROUP BY tab2.user_id
HAVING count(DISTINCT tab3.permissions) = 2
INTERSECT
SELECT tab2.user_id
FROM tab2
WHERE tab2.shop IN ('shop_A', 'shop_C')
GROUP BY tab2.user_id
HAVING count(DISTINCT tab2.shop) = 2
```